# keycloak 21.1.1 not able to load ssl certificate

Tags: keycloak

I am trying to run a keycloak server using docker compose behind an SSL but for some reason the certificate is not loading.

Version 21.1.1

DockerCompose.yml

```
  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:21.1.1
    hostname: keycloak
    container_name: keycloak
    volumes:
      - ./imports:/opt/keycloak/data/import
      - ./certs:/opt/keycloak/certs
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "443:8443"
      - "80:8080"
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
      KC_HTTP_ENABLED: true
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT: false
      KC_DB: mysql
      KC_DB_URL_HOST: db
      KC_DB_URL_PROPERTIES : '?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true'
      KC_DB_SCHEMA: keycloak
      KC_DB_USERNAME: mysqluser
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: 'password'
      KC_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_FILE: /opt/keycloak/certs/fullchain.pem
      KC_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_KEY_FILE: /opt/keycloak/certs/privkey.pem
    depends_on:
      - db
    command: -v start
```

I copied the certs from /etc/letsencrypt/live/*/.pem folder in a folder where docker can read and gave full permission to that new folder. (sudo chmod -R 777 /certs)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]